# Reducing the zero row/column of a matrix

Tags: matrix

I have a $8\times 8$ matrix, whose 2,3,5,8-th row and columns are zero:

```
mat = {{1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2 E^(-I t w1), -(1/2) E^(-2 I t w1 - I t w2), 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {-(1/2) E^(I theta1 - I t w2), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  1/2 E^(I theta1 - I t w1 - I t w2), 
  1/2 E^(I theta1 - 2 I t w1 - 2 I t w2), 
  0}, {1/2 E^(I theta1 + I theta2 - I t w2), 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -(1/2) E^(I theta1 + I theta2 - I t w1 - I t w2), 
  1/2 E^(I theta1 + I theta2 - 2 I t w1 - 2 I t w2), 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

The above matrix looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is, by removing the row/column with zero entries, I want to condense this into $4\times 4$ matrix. How can I do this?

Comment: fyi, MatrixForm of your code do not match what you show as screen shot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mat0 = {{m[1, 1], 0, 0, m[1, 4], 0, m[1, 6], m[1, 7], 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {m[4, 1], 0, 0, m[4, 4], 0, m[4, 6], m[4, 7], 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {m[6, 1], 0, 0,  m[6, 4], 0, m[6, 6], m[6, 7], 0}, 
    {m[7, 1], 0, 0, m[7, 4], 0, m[7, 6], m[7, 7], 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

MatrixForm @ mat0
```

[image]

1. You can use [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) as follows:

```
mat1 = mat0[[{1, 4, 6, 7}, {1, 4, 6, 7}]];

MatrixForm @ mat1
```

[image]

2. You can also use [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) + [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) + [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html)

```
mat2 = Nest[Transpose @* DeleteCases[{0 ..}], mat0, 2];

MatrixForm @ mat2
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The display of the matrix you have do not agree with the code. But you can do

```
mat = {{m[1, 1], 0, 0, m[1, 4], 0, m[1, 6], m[1, 7], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {m[4, 1], 0, 0, m[4, 4], 0,
     m[4, 6], m[4, 7], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {m[6, 1], 0, 0, 
    m[6, 4], 0, m[6, 6], m[6, 7], 0}, {m[7, 1], 0, 0, m[7, 4], 0, 
    m[7, 6], m[7, 7], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DeleteCases[mat, {0 ..}, Infinity];
Transpose@DeleteCases[Transpose[%], {0 ..}, Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Define:

```
delEmpty = {0 ..} -> Nothing;
```

Execute:

```
(Transpose[Transpose[(mat /. delEmpty)] /. delEmpty]) // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 m(1,1) & m(1,4) & m(1,6) & m(1,7) \\
 m(4,1) & m(4,4) & m(4,6) & m(4,7) \\
 m(6,1) & m(6,4) & m(6,6) & m(6,7) \\
 m(7,1) & m(7,4) & m(7,6) & m(7,7) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$